How to move edge until it touches/aligns with vertex
How do I move selected object on one axis so that one edge aligns/snaps with an unselected vertex?
Red edge in first picture is the one I want to align. Arrow is pointing to vertex I want the edge to snap to
Snapping to vertices and edges didn't work for me (last pic shows snapping, and it doesn't work. FYI I tried selecting "Edge" "Vertex" and went through all the "Snap With" options.)





Yes I have tried that. I edited my post to show it

could you please show the Snap panel settings?

@moonboots I updated the post. I'm quite sure I tried all the "Snap To" options, though I am open to suggestions

@moonboots I did mention in the post that I tried that

oops sorry I misundrstood

When you used the snap, did you have the edge selected as the active element and the Pivot point set to Active?

@Cornivius I believe I've tried that. But it wouldn't make a difference in the snapping, only the orientation of the movement. I have no problem with the orientation or axis, only the snapping

I've come up with a solution, though I'm still open to other maybe more efficient solutions.

